# getResourceAsStream works for json file but not other formats

Tags: java, json, jar, resources, shapefile

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2

When I call getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.json") then a valid input stream is returned. When I add a shapefile to the same directory as test.json and call getClass().getResourceAsStream("/shapefile.shp") then a null inputstream is returned.

Why is this? Is it due to the fact that json can be returned as a stream but the shapefile format can't?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got to ask, since there isn't an obvious reason why it wouldn't work otherwise: are you 100% sure that `/shapefile.shp` exists? (/and is incorporated into the jar?)

Comment: "Is it due to the fact that json can be returned as a stream but the shapefile format can't?" Nope. They're both just sequences of bytes.

Comment: @AndyTurner [This](http://i.imgur.com/Z1qOjq2.png?1) shows the inputstream as null, the county json line at the top returns a valid inputstream as expected.

The file system looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/tBXvHlC.png)

Comment: Wrong...it does work.

Comment: @pczeus What do you mean? It doesn't work, I get a null input stream.